# Voltage - Current Relationship (IV graphs)

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, short-circuits

This is probably a really simple question but for some reason, I'm finding it difficult to grasp at an atomic level. My physics textbook has a statement that says:

"As the voltage across a component is increased, the current in the component also increases"

This is the basis for the Current-Voltage (IV) graph seen below:

[image]

However, I don't understand how we are supposed to increase the potential difference across just one component. Furthermore, I don't get why increasing voltage across the component should increase the flow of charge (current).

So my 2 questions are:

1. How do we increase the voltage across just one component without increasing resistance?
2. Why does increasing voltage mean there has to be an increase in the flow of charge (current)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model

Comment: Do you know the definition of potential difference (voltage)?

Comment: No. Not in much detail. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the voltage across a component is just the energy lost by every coulomb of charge.

Comment: Anonymous do you know the Drude model of conduction in metals?

Comment: I'm 15 so I haven't exactly jumped into that end of the pool yet. This is just something in my high school physics book that wasn't really explained. IK that voltage across a component is the voltage taken by the component per coloumb. But I don't see how increasing voltage, essentially increasing the electric p.d of charge increases the speed of the charge.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have a simple system with just one component, then increasing the voltage across the component is simply a matter of changing the voltage in your source. If your system is just a battery and a resistor, by replacing the battery for a stronger one, or two batteries in series you would increase the total voltage across the resistor. If you want more fine tuning of the voltage, there are [power supplies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_supply) in which you can regulate the output voltage.
2. The voltage or more correctly, the *voltage difference* across a component is proportional to the energy a charge would gain or lose by traversing that component. There are many ways to explain why a voltage difference generates a current.

A simple way to understand this is that in physics, the systems always try to minimize the energy, which in this case means carrying the charges to a point of lower energy (across the component), generating a current.

A more detailed way would be to know that a potential difference causes an electric field to be present inside the component, and that [electric fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_field) generate a force on the charges inside the component, accelerating it.

One then could question where the kinetic energy gained by the charges go. The answer is that when the charges are traversing a resistor they "colide" with the atoms inside it, dissipating heat. That is why resistors heat up when you put a current through them. A mathematical way to describe this is through the [*Drude model*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model), mentioned by @JunSeo-He.

More detailed models of this exist, but I hope these explanations will cover your basic doubts.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This explanation was very very helpful in my understanding of voltage. Does this electric field exist in all components?

Comment: Also, do you have any sources or books I can follow in order to obtain knowledge on the nature of current, voltage and resistance?

Comment: Any books, papers or websites will be very helpful

Comment: Short answer: yes. A non-zero electric field exists wherever there is a difference in electric potential (voltage). Inside wires and resistors, the electric field causes the current. Between capacitor plates there is no flow of current, but the accumulation of charges on the plates also causes an electric field to appear.

Comment: I will try and find some sources.

Comment: Thanks, Just out of curiosity, what books did you read in order to gain insight? I'm planning on pursuing a degree in either physics or electrical engineering and to do those, I need a good understanding of how a simple circuit works. I want to read more on the topic but don't know where to begin

Comment: I'm having some difficulties finding good websites and books at high-school level, but have you heard about the Crash Course youtube channel? I think that's a good place to start. Their Physics course, Episodes 26 to 32 should cover all these things we discussed and a bit more: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OoO5d5P0Jn4&list=PL8dPuuaLjXtN0ge7yDk_UA0ldZJdhwkoV

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying. I'll check their videos out.

Comment: Also, I've seen recommended the book [University Physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_Physics) by Young and Freedman, but as the name says it's better suited for undergraduate students. You can also meddle with the Wikipedia pages on the subjects and see if anything interests you. But most importantly, I would recommend that you also do lots of problem solving on simple exercises, as you will need that for entry exams in universities.

Comment: Finally, I just find out this website has a [chat room for high-school physics](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54160/problem-solving-strategies).
People might be able to better help you there. Good luck!

Comment: I'm running out of ways to say thank you.  This is extremely helpful. Wow. I appreciate it a lot